# I want to create a user credential python script wherein the data is stored in a csv file and the user should be unique

Tags: python, csv, user-input

I want to create a user credential python script wherein the data is stored in a csv file and the user should be unique. I am getting duplicate values that are being displayed over and over again in the csv file with same data inputs. I tried every possible way that I know but it isn't showing the result. My code is below:

```
def create_credentials(self, user_id, username, publisher, display_name):
    with open('file_1.csv', 'r+') as file_open:
    # creating a csv reader object
        existing_users = csv.reader(file_open)
    for i in existing_users:
        print(i)
    # To check if a user exists with the same data or not.
    if user_id in existing_users:
        print("Sorry User ID already exists in file")
    else:
        if user_id == '':
            user_id = input("Enter a valid user id")
        self.__user_id = user_id

    if username not in existing_users:
        if username == '':
            username = input("Enter a valid username")
        self.__username = username
    else:
        print("Sorry Username already exists")
```

The indentation is correct in my code, it is looking a bit distorted here. I want to make unique records and not get duplicates if I try to create a duplicate record it should simply give me an error or a print() message stating the record is already existing in file. Also, I tried doing some check on internet and I got to know that the file is not loading all the data I guess. Can someone help me on this? Thanx in advance.

Comment: This doesn't write anything, and it doesn't recreate your issue. To fix the indentation, you can just add 4 spaces where it needs more.

Comment: You also want to take into account what column you're looking at in the csv reader, but that's beyond the scope of this question (different bug).

Comment: This is not the entire code. I am generating a dataframe after this using pandas and appending it to the csv file in append mode. I want to read the entire file and append a new record at the end. that is why I am not looking at a specific column. I just want to know that if I enter the same USER_ID and USERNAME as a new record then why it is not giving me the print statement i.e., print("Sorry user id already exists in file")

Comment: It would be helpful to create a minimal reproducible example instead of providing the code snippet of a method. In best case, your problem should be reproducible by copy pasting.

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the csv file, but doesn't remember it. You'll want to store the usernames and id's as you iterate over the reader so you can use them later. Here's your code:

```
existing_users = csv.reader(file_open)
for i in existing_users:
    print(i)
```

Looking at the documentation,
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader
we see that csv.reader returns a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile.

But an iterator can only be read once:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators

Since it iterated over the full csv file in this code, it is done. Any further attempt to read from "existing_users" will result in a stop iteration exception, which is what happens when you use "in".

Comment: So, what should I do in order to save contents to a csv file and not have duplicate records in it.

Comment: If you fix your code to detect the duplicate, you can avoid adding any more. To get rid of the ones that are already in there, you'll probably have to re-write the csv file. You can't delete stuff by appending lines.

Comment: Got the required output. Thank You